# Angular animations in Ionic 3 using Stagger

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, ionic3, angular-animations

I followed a simple [tutorial](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/78/Creating-Stagger-Animations-in-Angular-4) of Angular animations using [angular/animations](https://angular.io/guide/animations). It was quite simple but the animation does not work or am I implementing it wrong in my **component**

Here is my **animation code below**:

```
animations: [
    trigger('listAnimation', [
      transition('* => *', [
        query(':enter', style({ opacity: 0 }), {optional: true}),
        query(':enter', stagger('300ms', [
          animate('1s ease-in', keyframes([
            style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-75%)', offset: 0}),
            style({opacity: .5, transform: 'translateY(35px)',  offset: 0.3}),
            style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0)',     offset: 1.0}),
          ]))]), {optional: true})
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

and in my **html**

```
<div>
    <ion-card id="list" [@listAnimation]="lists.length" class="box" *ngFor="let list of lists; let i = index">
      <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-4 text-center>
            <p>{{list.time}}</p> 
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-2 text-center>
            <p>{{list.amount}}</p>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-2 text-center>
            <p>{{list.fees}}</p> 
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-2 text-center>
            <p>{{list.balance}}</p> 
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-2>
            <button ion-button icon-only clear small (tap)="viewMore(list)">
              <ion-icon color="listColorIcon" name="app-svg-back-next" class="icon-sm"></ion-icon>
            </button>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-card>
  </div>
```

My goal is to have an animation like in the link of the tutorial above. I want each item of array to fade in one after another which I couldn't achieve.

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.